# Adding a product to cart WooCommerce?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to create a query or STORED procedure of how to add products to cart in WooCommerce database! 
I don't excatly know the structure of the database for this particularly case,i dont know where is stored the table that contains the cart.
I would appreciate it if someone would help me!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What errors did you get? It may be worthwhile to read [**how to ask a good question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried everything regarding creating queries for this task. my problem is that i don't excantly know where are stored the products added to the cart,in which table they are stored

Comment: Products are simply a post type. Products added to the cart are stored in the Session variables and aren't added to the database. That's the best I can do with your question as it stands now. If you edit the question to explain what you are doing, someone might be able to give you an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the version of WooCommerce you're using, cart items are either stored as PHP `$_SESSION` variables, or `WP_SESSION` variables. In other words, there's no table with your data.

[Read more](http://mikejolley.com/2013/12/problems-with-cart-sessions-and-woocommerce/).